# Google sheets residual formula values after source data removed

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

This happens to me quite a bit and I'm not really certain how to word it properly to search google for a solution, but whenever I populate my data sheet, my formula works fine.  But then when I clear that data, the formula still works and shows `N/A`, or "" if I use `IFERROR`, in the `FORMULA` cell, but all of the previous values beyond that are still present. Like "ghost" values or something.  They don't seem to be calculated in other formulas, but it is distracting and I'd just assume they not be there.

Any ideas?  Is this something that happens regularly or am I just special?  I don't recall if it is *always* a `QUERY`, but it happens to be in the screenshot below.

This sheet contains sensitive customer information, so I can't share it, but if necessary, I can make a copy and try to remove all of that information.

[image]

Comment: could be a bug in your sheet which means you won't be able to reproduce it in another sheet if I am right :)

Comment: Yeah, you may be right!  I made a copy of the sheet with the error and the error didn't copy over.  At least, I haven't tried to reproduce it just yet.  I may just have to make a new file and copy everything over formula-by-formula.  Ugh!

Comment: you are supposed to contact Google Sheets support and request a repair of your sheet. they would check it and if it's not beyond repair they can fix it for you. but yeah, you can save a month worth of communication with them if you just recreate your sheet